# How do I get OK Google to respond to only my voice?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s-6, google-now

OK Google on my husband's phone (a Galaxy S6 running Nougat) responds to both his voice and mine. We've tried retraining the voice model several times, and activating Trusted Voice under Smart Lock, and neither of those fixed it.

Any help would be appreciated!